# Different results using == and find in MATLAB

Tags: matlab

I have created a sparse matrix using MEX and also created a sparse matrix using MATLAB. To fill in the values of the matrix i have used same formula.
Now to check if the both the matrices are equal I used result=(A==B). result returns 1 for all indices, which implies that all the matrix elements are equal.
But if I do find(A-B) it returns some indices, which indicates that at these indices the values are non-zero. How is this possible?

Note: When i compare the value at these indices it shows equal !

Comment: What is the result of A-B? If it is really small inequality may be result of limited numerical precision.

Comment: Show an example of a value pair where they are equal but A-B is not zero.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'm guessing you have values of [infinity](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/inf.html) cropping up in your matrices at the same points. For example:

```
>> A = Inf;
>> B = Inf;
>> A == B

ans =

     1  %# They are treated as equal...

>> A-B

ans =

   NaN  %# ...but their difference actually results in NaN...

>> find(A-B)

ans =

     1  %# ...which is treated as a non-zero value.
```

The discrepancy here results from the fact that certain operations involving infinity result in [`NaN`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/nan.html) values. You can check to see if you have any infinities in `A` and `B` by using the function [ISINF](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/isinf.html) like so:

```
any(isinf(A(:)))
any(isinf(B(:)))
```

And if you get a value of 1 (i.e. true), then the presence of infinities is likely the source of your discrepancy.